# WPF: Restyling a window?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, expression-blend

does anyone know if its possible to restyle a window in wpf. Or even better any tutorials or samples?

Basically i would like to change the minimize and maximize buttons - oh and the close button to be slightly bigger....

I have expression blend....

Is this possible?

I saw some samples in infragistics sample apps which have some great looking forms and as far as i can tell it doesn't use any custom wpf controls...

Any ideas really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As quick solution would be to set the WindowStyle="None" on your window, then create your own minimize and close buttons. Hook up the event/command for the new buttons to manipulate the window.